# Solr Streaming Expression using PHP Curl

Tags: solr

I am trying to implement the following streaming expression using PHP curl.

```
curl --data-urlencode 'expr=search(enron_emails,
                   q="from:1800flowers*",
                   fl="from, to",
                   sort="from asc",
                   qt="/export")' http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/stream
```

Above curl request from command-line works fine. However, running the same using php curl does not work. I've used the following PHP code.

```
function streamSolrData() {
    $url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/stream';

    $data['expr']['search'] = "enron_emails";
    $data['expr']['search']['q'] = 'from:1800flowers*';
    $data['expr']['search']['fl'] = "from, to";
    $data['expr']['search']['sort'] = "from asc";
    $data['expr']['search']['qt'] = "/export";

    $data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();

    if ($ch) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
            'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data))                                                                       
        );                                                                                                                   


        $response = curl_exec($ch);
    }
}
```

Above query just returns `{"result-set":{"docs":[{"EXCEPTION":null,"EOF":true}]}}` without any results.

Any idea what i am missing here?

I've found the answer for this. Ideally solr is expecting to pass single parameter called expr. Following is the solution.

#### SOLUTION

```
function streamSolrData() {
        $url = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/enron_emails/stream';

        $data['expr'] = 'search(enron_emails,
                                   q="from:1800flowers*",
                                   fl="from, to",
                                   sort="from asc",
                                   qt="/export")'

        $ch = curl_init();

        if ($ch) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                                                     
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending JSON, but the structure given for a streaming expression is not JSON, so encoding the content as JSON will give an invalid request.

If you look at the query:

```
expr=search(enron_emails,
               q="from:1800flowers*",
               fl="from, to",
               sort="from asc",
               qt="/export")
```

.. this is not a valid JSON object or a JSON structure in any way.

Instead, use `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, which includes the content unprocessed in a POST request body:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
           urlencode('expr=search(enron_emails,
               q="from:1800flowers*",
               fl="from, to",
               sort="from asc",
               qt="/export")'));
```

Comment: What happens? What does the solr server log say about what you're sending it?

Comment: Solr server log shows the following error

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.expr.StreamExpressionParser.generateStreamExpression(StreamExpressionParser.java:46)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.expr.StreamExpressionParser.parse(StreamExpressionParser.java:37)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.io.stream.expr.StreamFactory.constructStream(StreamFactory.java:234)
...
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh, i've found solution for this. I've updated the answer